# Error "Could not find any typelib for Gtk" with Python3 and GTK3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, gobject-introspection

I cannot make Python3 work with GTK3. I'm in a cluster context and I had everything recompiled from the sources.

When I run a simple example :

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I have the following error :

```
    ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "gtk3_example.py", line 2, in 
        from gi.repository import Gtk
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Gtk'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are typically additional packages to install depending on what you want to introspect. The one I found that was crucial was gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (or 2.0 depending which version you are coding against).

Comment: Originally my problem was that I had to install from sources all the software stack with their dependencies. So the find-the-good-package solution was not an option. But I agree that in more classical situations it may be the good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the compiled version of GTK3 that was not referenced in gobject-introspection.

It is simple to check the problem by listing the `.typelib` files in gobject-introspection

```
    $ which g-ir-scanner
    /Produits/publics/x86_64.Linux.RH6/gobject-introspection/1.40.0/bin/g-ir-scanner

    $ ls /Produits/publics/x86_64.Linux.RH6/gobject-introspection/1.40.0/lib/girepository-1.0/
    cairo-1.0.typelib     fontconfig-2.0.typelib  GIRepository-2.0.typelib  GModule-2.0.typelib  win32-1.0.typelib   xlib-2.0.typelib
    DBus-1.0.typelib      freetype2-2.0.typelib   GL-1.0.typelib            GObject-2.0.typelib  xfixes-4.0.typelib  xrandr-1.3.typelib
    DBusGLib-1.0.typelib  Gio-2.0.typelib         GLib-2.0.typelib          libxml2-2.0.typelib  xft-2.0.typelib
```

The problem should be solved by recompiling GTK (and its dependencies) with the configure option `--enable-introspection=yes`.

Comment: And how to recompile GTK?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think it was a pretty classic get the tgz, configure, make, make install. "--enable-introspection=yes" refers to a configure option. Are you sure you cannot solve your problem through the packaging system ? (recompiling all that stuff was a pain, that I remember clearly)

Comment: I was working on mac, and installed the dependencies with brew install, I am not able to option for recompiling them.

Comment: I'm no mac expert so I can't help you on that. Recompiling is always possible but it is quite complex if you're not used to (setup a dev environment, get all the dependencies manualy and so on). Maybe a VM or a docker could be simpler for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GTK
```

Comment: How/why does this solve the problem?  It very well may solve it, but unless you at least partially explain the logic of why or how, it's not really a complete answer.  Thanks!