# pyGtk: Gtk missing error when get version

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, pygobject

When I startup `/usr/bin/sniff` which is a GUI monitor of dogtail I got below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sniff", line 13, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 48, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

And I execute the command `python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk'` I got:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk
```

Any help?
Thanks.

System: CentOS release 6.2(Final)

Python-2.7.3

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037006/error-could-not-find-any-typelib-for-gtk-with-python3-and-gtk3

Comment: On Mac OS X you need to install two packages to avoid this error: `brew install gtk+3 pygobject3`.