# Python 3.4 importerror gtk

Tags: python, gtk, importerror, pygi-aio

When I try to import gtk using:
`from gi.repository import Gtk`
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\importer.py", line 100, in find_module
'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk, introspection typelib not found
```

In case it's important:
Windows 10
Python 3.4.3
PyGi from [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar)

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037006/error-could-not-find-any-typelib-for-gtk-with-python3-and-gtk3

Comment: @Nikaidoh I'm on windows

Comment: Did you install GTK+ 3? To do so, you will need MSYS2. See the GTK+ website for details.